# Why are some book suggestion posts accepted, but not mine?

Tags: discussion, support, on-hold

Questions like [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
 [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) are accepted, but not this [The Definitive Python Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720522/the-definitive-python-book-guide-and-list), it was put on hold.

Why is this so?

Comment: Those questions are exceptions, they are only approved because they are backed by the community who continues to maintain the answers. If you haven't talked to the [python SO community](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) before, you'll have a hard time with your question.

Comment: I for one would not help maintain such a list. Would you, for the next 10 years?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Comment: Here, [go help maintain this for a while](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) - *then* see if you still wanna run a separate q&a.

Comment: Because we're scared of those C++ maniacs.  You we aren't afraid of.  Sucket.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first two questions were asked 6 years ago, when these questions were still accepted. Now they are not anymore, and that's why your question is put on hold.

Comment: In addition, those two are actively maintained by the respective communities, which is ... *rare*. Also, they are wiki-locked, so noone can add new answers.

Comment: As @Deduplicator states, the fact that they are maintained is also a huge factor. If they weren't, they'd probably end up deleted with the rest of the list of links garbage.

Comment: I think it's unfortunate how the standards have changed, those types of questions are useful.