# Is "give me a collection of books" an on-topic question on SO?

Tags: discussion, questions

I stumbled on [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), a question which attempts to collect a list of good books for C++. While this question might be useful for a lot of people (hence the number of upvotes), does it qualify for the SO standards?

Some particularities that I noticed:

- no accepted answer, despite is was asked a long time ago
- the question has only one non-deleted answer, all other answers got deleted through time (some of them got merged in the top answer)
- seems off-topic by the current standards, as it asks for 3rd parties

Shouldn't this kind of information be kept in the tag wiki, instead?

**Update.** Just run into a somewhat related question: [How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer). The question is no longer considered on-topic, and was locked with a clear note from the moderator:

[image: lock note for off-topic question]

Maybe we should apply a similar treatment to the question in discussion too.

Comment: It [comes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290701/why-are-some-book-suggestion-posts-accepted-but-not-mine) up [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354696/can-we-have-a-community-wiki-page-on-the-definitive-python-book-guide-and-list) and [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342966/should-there-be-the-definitive-web-development-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: TL;DR on those posts yivi referred to: The C++ book list has a special position because it's exceptionally well-maintained by the community, just like the associated [tag:C++-faq] tag which is a meta tag and would be deleted if it didn't have this position. Imo it's too long to be moved to the C++ wiki, and if it's not causing problems it's all fine. We get some problems with people using this to justify their own book lists, but can handle those one at a time.

Comment: What a load of crap. We all know the C++ tag held a knife to shog's neck and threatened to show him the black stuff inside if he didn't let the baby have its binky. So the question stands unclosed. You don't want to cross those C++ bastids. They don't gaf.

Comment: It shouldn't be here anymore - the GitHub page it had was actually promising - but it's here because the people who want to maintain it don't want to give it up over here, but the site itself can't really keep it around.

Comment: It should be kept.  It wouldn't be a valid question on modern SO, but it does have useful information and it is maintained.  This crops up every few months, and the response should continue to be the same as on the last N times.  And I'm still annoyed that the corresponding [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (10k users) was deleted — despite it being maintained too.

Comment: That's an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/388242/revisions?page=6), those are somewhat exception, they appears before current standards of SO were defined, think of it as it's your old neighbor, who is strange, but harmless. You shouldn't ask such questions now, nor let someone else do (flag and downvote).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I prefer that SE listen to reason and not just seniority.

Comment: Just a thought, can we simply close and lock it? Given the amount of effort and the resources it provides, it might not be the best idea to delete it, however if we keep it open then we create a precedent for other languages to ask for such privileged treatment.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth the only good reason not to remove it is "because it's not anywhere else", to which the answer is "then just move it". This has already happened with the free programming books question. I don't see what is the show stopper.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth wherever you like. We have cases where information has moved or replaced by a better version elsewhere and has thrived. Now, show me a case where that didn't happen.

Comment: These abominations should be deleted, not locked. These pages are nothing more than a collection of opinions and dead links. Horrible and useless. Nuke it from orbit.

Answer (score 19):

No, book collection questions are not on topic.

Should they be? That gets into all sorts of different issues that have been hashed and rehashed several times over the years. Mostly it boils down into not wanting large unorganized lists of links that break over time to material which becomes outdated, as well as a little bit of a nod towards maintaining topicality.

This one example is a "broken window". It is a slight exception that has been made to keep, with the understanding that the list will be well maintained. However, per its existence, many users often wonder if different languages should also have such lists.

You are right to question it, and perhaps it was hard to find a succinct post here on meta (I couldn't, and tried, or I would have just dupehammered it), but in the end there is a historical precedence for retaining this post while at the same time realizing that the site as it sits today is a different place.

We don't need any more book lists.

> Shouldn't this kind of information be kept in the tag wiki, instead?

I wish that tag wikis would get more attention, and that they had a better format. So, in theory, yes it really should; but, in practice, it often is not and also would not fit very well in the current tag wiki design.

Comment: "I wish that tag wikis would get more attention" *Tag wikis are a handy place to stash information that needs to be updated frequently and **needs to be referenced frequently.*** -- [Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370472/792066)

Comment: By attention, I meant feature development. Although I see how perhaps that was not as clear as it could have been. Tag wikis are hidden, and it is clear from Shog's answer that my base premise here is also correct: without an improvement to design, the tag wikis see almost no traffic and have a weak format to support the information they are capable of supporting.

Comment: My point is that we need totally the opposite. Tag wiki sucks not because they have some kind of design flaw, they suck because nobody search for them nor crosslink them.

Comment: If a feature can only be found by someone who knows where it is and links to it, then that is a pretty glaring design flaw. One of many with tag wikis. They need more structure to support the type of information one would expect from a wiki as well as the ability to be discovered through the interface.

Comment: "If a feature can only be found by someone who knows where it is and links to it", if the tag wiki said "list of books", you think Google is not going to find it and show it in the results? I doubt it. The only reason why nobody seems to find it, is because it lacks the necessary ranking that is given be crossreferences, and that's the responsibility of the people creating the resource to bear.

Comment: @Braiam - I think you fundamentally misunderstand the process that drives web traffic. In addition to that, our own users, some long time users, are not even *aware* of the tag wiki as a feature, so on top of Google not finding it (completely unrelated to your points) our own users don't even know that it is available as a feature in order to be created such content. Moreover, as a feature, it is weak in design.

Comment: Agree that the tag wiki is technically the appropriate place for this. Not sure where I stand on the "but they suck so we won't" argument because two wrongs don't make a right. However overall I support keeping the book list as it is until we do have something better. Remember, leaving the EU is not the same as not being in the EU!

Comment: dupe candidates: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344603/103167 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296094/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt - I did see and consider those. However, the first has no answers, and the second is more about deleting the book lists. I did strongly consider the second one though, but felt it didn't address the overall topicality and was more broad whereas this was still rather focused on one post. Moreover, I am still not always convinced that discussions are really that duplicate.

Answer (score 13):

It's off-topic, it's even stated in the "recommendation" close reason:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book**, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: To be fair, the question is for books plural :P

Answer (score 9):

It's technically off-topic, but occasionally the rules get bent for exceptional cases, such as this one. *(See also: off-topic political ramblings posing as meta questions.)* The use of the post as a duplicate-target and general reference page is so astronomically huge as to be worthwhile.

Of course, "it's useful" is not generally sufficient to accept something, and it's not sufficient to make something on-topic. The C++ community in particular seems to have a particular need for this particular post because poor C++ teaching is so very common, far more so than for many/most/all other languages.

Arguably, though, yes, it ought instead to be in a tag wiki, or an external wiki page, or something.

Comment: Notably, we killed off the C book list earlier this year. There weren't enough people maintaining it and the quality had turned awful. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355588/the-c-book-list-has-gone-haywire-what-to-do-with-it

Comment: @Lundin To be fair that's not the case for the C++ list AFAIK, though I concede I haven't been keeping an eye on it for a while

Comment: You don't spend a lot of time on `javascript`, do you? I think not, or you may not have made that comment about C++ teaching being worse that other languages... :P

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, I don't 